# Question on a mutiple improper integral

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose  $a\in R^n$, $a \neq 0$, $p > 0$.Calculate $$ \int_{R^n} |xa|^p e^{-||x||^2}dx_1dx_2\cdots dx_n $$ $$xa=x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\cdots+x_na_n$$
I tried to use the following methods:let $y_1=x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\cdots+x_na_n,y_2=x_2,y_3=x_3,\cdots,y_n=x_n$,but I failed.
I think it may be related to Gamma Funtion.

Comment: better to write $x\cdot a$ instead to indicate dot product.

Comment: *Hint.* By the rotational symmetry, you may assume $a$ is of the form $a=(\|a\|, 0, \ldots, 0)$.